# let vim show the typing command on the status line

Tags: vim

I'd like let the vim show the command I'm typing in the status line,
I searched the google, and get he answer is put the

> set showcmd

into .vimrc file, but i did, and when i type the delete command:

> 3 dd

the number 3 is not show in the status line.

and I also have the setting:

> laststatus=2

what's wrong with my profile?

PS. This is my .vimrc file

```
set nocompatible
set ruler
"autocomplate the command in the vim command line status
set wildmenu
syntax on
" Enable filetype plugins
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
" Set to auto read when a file is changed from the outside
set autoread
" Configure backspace so it acts as it should act
set backspace=eol,start,indent
set whichwrap+=<,>,h,l
" Show the command in the status line
set showcmd
" Ignore case when searching
set ignorecase
" When searching try to be smart about cases 
set smartcase
" Highlight search results
set hlsearch
" Makes search act like search in modern browsers
set incsearch
" Show matching brackets when text indicator is over them
set showmatch
" How many tenths of a second to blink when matching brackets
set mat=2
" No annoying sound on errors
set noerrorbells
set novisualbell
set t_vb=
set tm=500
" Turn backup off, since most stuff is in SVN, git et.c anyway...
set nobackup
set nowb
set noswapfile
" Use spaces instead of tabs
set expandtab

" Be smart when using tabs 
set smarttab

" 1 tab == 4 spaces
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4

" Linebreak on 500 characters
set lbr
set tw=500

set ai "Auto indent
set si "Smart indent
set wrap "Wrap lines

set clipboard=unnamedplus

" Return to last edit position when opening files (You want this!)
autocmd BufReadPost *
     \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
     \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
     \ endif
" Remember info about open buffers on close
set viminfo^=%

"Press space to clear search highlighting and any message already displayed.
nnoremap <silent> <Space> :silent noh<Bar>echo<CR>

"""""""""vim plugin manage""""""""""""""""""""
set nocompatible               " be iMproved
filetype off                   " required!

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required! 
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
" My Bundles here:
"
" original repos on github
"Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
"Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
"Bundle 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
"Bundle 'tpope/vim-rails.git'
Bundle 'Shougo/neocomplcache'
Bundle 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Bundle 'nvie/vim-flake8'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Bundle 'klen/python-mode'
" vim-scripts repos
"Bundle 'L9'
"Bundle 'FuzzyFinder'
" non github repos
"Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" git repos on your local machine (ie. when working on your own plugin)
"Bundle 'file:///Users/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
" ...

filetype plugin indent on     " required!
"
" Brief help
" :BundleList          - list configured bundles
" :BundleInstall(!)    - install(update) bundles
" :BundleSearch(!) foo - search(or refresh cache first) for foo
" :BundleClean(!)      - confirm(or auto-approve) removal of unused bundles
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" NOTE: comments after Bundle command are not allowed..

""""""""""""""plugin setting""""""""""""""""""""
"Note: This option must set it in .vimrc(_vimrc).  NOT IN .gvimrc(_gvimrc)!
" Disable AutoComplPop.
let g:acp_enableAtStartup = 0
" Use neocomplcache.
let g:neocomplcache_enable_at_startup = 1
" Use smartcase.
let g:neocomplcache_enable_smart_case = 1
" Set minimum syntax keyword length.
let g:neocomplcache_min_syntax_length = 3
let g:neocomplcache_lock_buffer_name_pattern = '\*ku\*'

" Enable heavy features.
" Use camel case completion.
"let g:neocomplcache_enable_camel_case_completion = 1
" Use underbar completion.
"let g:neocomplcache_enable_underbar_completion = 1

" Define dictionary.
let g:neocomplcache_dictionary_filetype_lists = {
    \ 'default' : '',
    \ 'vimshell' : $HOME.'/.vimshell_hist',
    \ 'scheme' : $HOME.'/.gosh_completions'
        \ }

" Define keyword.
if !exists('g:neocomplcache_keyword_patterns')
    let g:neocomplcache_keyword_patterns = {}
endif
let g:neocomplcache_keyword_patterns['default'] = '\h\w*'

" Plugin key-mappings.
inoremap <expr><C-g>     neocomplcache#undo_completion()
inoremap <expr><C-l>     neocomplcache#complete_common_string()

" Recommended key-mappings.
" <CR>: close popup and save indent.
inoremap <silent> <CR> <C-r>=<SID>my_cr_function()<CR>
function! s:my_cr_function()
  return neocomplcache#smart_close_popup() . "\<CR>"
  " For no inserting <CR> key.
  "return pumvisible() ? neocomplcache#close_popup() : "\<CR>"
endfunction
" <TAB>: completion.
inoremap <expr><TAB>  pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<TAB>"
" <C-h>, <BS>: close popup and delete backword char.
inoremap <expr><C-h> neocomplcache#smart_close_popup()."\<C-h>"
inoremap <expr><BS> neocomplcache#smart_close_popup()."\<C-h>"
inoremap <expr><C-y>  neocomplcache#close_popup()
inoremap <expr><C-e>  neocomplcache#cancel_popup()
" Close popup by <Space>.
"inoremap <expr><Space> pumvisible() ? neocomplcache#close_popup() : "\<Space>"

" For cursor moving in insert mode(Not recommended)
"inoremap <expr><Left>  neocomplcache#close_popup() . "\<Left>"
"inoremap <expr><Right> neocomplcache#close_popup() . "\<Right>"
"inoremap <expr><Up>    neocomplcache#close_popup() . "\<Up>"
"inoremap <expr><Down>  neocomplcache#close_popup() . "\<Down>"
" Or set this.
"let g:neocomplcache_enable_cursor_hold_i = 1
" Or set this.
"let g:neocomplcache_enable_insert_char_pre = 1

" AutoComplPop like behavior.
"let g:neocomplcache_enable_auto_select = 1

" Shell like behavior(not recommended).
"set completeopt+=longest
"let g:neocomplcache_enable_auto_select = 1
"let g:neocomplcache_disable_auto_complete = 1
"inoremap <expr><TAB>  pumvisible() ? "\<Down>" : "\<C-x>\<C-u>"

" Enable omni completion.
autocmd FileType css setlocal omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
autocmd FileType html,markdown setlocal omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType python setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType xml setlocal omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags

" Enable heavy omni completion.
if !exists('g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns')
  let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns = {}
endif
let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns.php = '[^. \t]->\h\w*\|\h\w*::'
let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns.c = '[^.[:digit:] *\t]\%(\.\|->\)'
let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns.cpp = '[^.[:digit:] *\t]\%(\.\|->\)\|\h\w*::'

" For perlomni.vim setting.
" https://github.com/c9s/perlomni.vim
let g:neocomplcache_omni_patterns.perl = '\h\w*->\h\w*\|\h\w*::'

"""""""""""""""plugin setting"""""""""""""""
autocmd BufWritePost *.py call Flake8()

"""""""""""""""plugin setting"""""""""""""""
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ Powerline\ 9
set laststatus=2

""""""""""""""""plugin setting """"""""""""" 
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

"""""""""""""""plugin setting """"""""""""""""""
" Python-mode
" Activate rope
" Keys:
" K             Show python docs
" <Ctrl-Space>  Rope autocomplete
" <Ctrl-c>g     Rope goto definition
" <Ctrl-c>d     Rope show documentation
" <Ctrl-c>f     Rope find occurrences
" <Leader>b     Set, unset breakpoint (g:pymode_breakpoint enabled)
" [[            Jump on previous class or function (normal, visual, operator modes)
" ]]            Jump on next class or function (normal, visual, operator modes)
" [M            Jump on previous class or method (normal, visual, operator modes)
" ]M            Jump on next class or method (normal, visual, operator modes)
let g:pymode_rope = 1

" Documentation
let g:pymode_doc = 1
let g:pymode_doc_key = 'K'

"Linting
let g:pymode_lint = 1
let g:pymode_lint_checker = "pyflakes,pep8"
" Auto check on save
let g:pymode_lint_write = 1

" Support virtualenv
let g:pymode_virtualenv = 1

" Enable breakpoints plugin
let g:pymode_breakpoint = 1
let g:pymode_breakpoint_key = '<leader>b'

" syntax highlighting
let g:pymode_syntax = 1
let g:pymode_syntax_all = 1
let g:pymode_syntax_indent_errors = g:pymode_syntax_all
let g:pymode_syntax_space_errors = g:pymode_syntax_all

" Don't autofold code
let g:pymode_folding = 0
```

Comment: Does it work if you start vim with the `-u NONE` option in order to skip all initializations and then only do `:set showcmd`?

Comment: It's not shown on status line, it will shown under the status line.

Comment: If you are pressing `3 dd` then "3" should show up until you hit the spacebar.  `3 dd` and `3dd` are different commands.

Comment: @RandyMorris If i pressing 3 dd ,then "E481 NO range allowed" will display in the bottom, does the command work well for you?

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli I tried the -u NONE option and only use the setting `set showcmd` it works! so, I'am wonder whether my .vimrc file is wrong with something :(

Comment: I solve the problem by add a extra line in vimrc file at the bottom.  **set showcmd**

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue while configuring my .vimrc .

It seems that some plugin overrides your configuration for `showcmd` option.
I suspect `Bundle 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}` one, because it changes styling.

So trying to move `set showcmd` line after plugins section, or even to the end of file can fix the problem.